# Is there an easy way to delete most variables but keep the loaded data for ongoing code?

Tags: python

The situation is, there is a for-loop which runs 100 times, sharing a same loaded data. As each single loop goes, it will create a growing number of variables which occupies a lot of memory resource and then further slows down the running speed. The code can be abstractly written as

```
data = sio.loadmat('very_big_data_set.mat')
for t in range(100):
    config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
    sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=config)
    var_1 = ...
    var_2 = ...


    var_10000 = ...
    model = ...

    sess.close()

    # The line below is a solution but it's very inconvinient
    del config, sess, var_1, ..., var_10000, model
```

My question is if there is a python command I can use to delete all of created variables during the for-loop but keep the loaded data for next loop? I know the method `del config, sess, var_1, ..., var_10000, model` but it requires me to list all of variables I want to delte. So I am looking for a more easy way, kind of like `del all except data`.

Comment: It seems like all your var_X variables should just be a list.

Comment: Something's not right here. For one thing, it's hard to make a for loop that creates a new variable in every iteration and binds it to a new name. For another thing, your program shouldn't be slowing down just because you're gradually using more memory. Can you provide a more concrete example? Preferably a [mcve] that runs.

Comment: @Kevin You definitely get a slowdown if memory consumption blows out of RAM and starts swapping to disk. I agree with the rest...

Comment: @Kevin Hi, I don't know why. But when I observe from from terminal screen using `htop`, the memory usage of CPU goes linearly (I guess) and continuously from loop-1 `702M/7.76G` to loop-100 `4.79G/7.76G`.

Comment: Look into better data types for the job, like `list` and `dict`, instead of trying to do the work of the language yourself. If you don't want to keep temporary values, just encapsulate the code and the variables into a function (look up `def`) and call it repeatedly - the variables will be in the local scope of the function and get removed automatically, while you can pass in anything shared as an argument.

Comment: Yeah, without more information on exactly what you are trying to achieve, I have to imagine that creating a bunch of variables like this is not the most efficient way to handle things.  Perhaps consider storing your "variables" in a dictionary with key being variable name.

Comment: @Grismar Good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you want to use variables that need to be cleaned up after you're done with it, especially if you're using them repeatedly, writing a function is a good idea:

```
def do_something(arg):
    # arg gets the same value as x (or points to the same thing)
    y = 10
    # now y exists, we can do do something with y and arg
    r = y + arg
    # now r, y and arg exist
    return r
    # once the function returns, arg no longer exists or references x
    # y and r are no longer referenced either and will no longer exist

for x in range(10)
    print(do_something(x))
    # here, y and r don't exist anymore, because the function has ended
# here, y and r don't exist, but x still does, since a loop variable sticks around
# capture all this in a function and call it and x would be cleaned up as well
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is reduced scope for your variable. Actually, your variables is global, which made the data present in memory until the program ends.

Here is an example of your needs:

```py
def data_valorisation(config, sess):
    # All theses variable will be deleted and recreated each time you call the function
    var_1 = ...
    var_2 = ...
    [...]
    var_10000 = ...
    model = ...

data = sio.loadmat('very_big_data_set.mat')
for t in range(100):
    config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
    sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=config)
    data_valorisation(config, sess)
    sess.close()
```

You should always put computation into function and avoid doing it in a global context. For this, you can use function or classes.

[Variables and scope](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html)